# Angular unchecked ng-class function

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working on a table that when a checkbox is checked it sets the TR green.  And after it's completed it highlights the TR in red at the end.

[Here is the JsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5487f896/4/)

My question is, how can you use an Angular function to determine if the checkboxes have the class pass and if not have the class fail when the button is clicked?  The function I have so far is

`$scope.statusCheck = function () {
        console.log('click');
        if ($scope.class != "pass") $scope.class = "fail";
        else $scope.class = "pass";
    };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see if the button was clicked and make conditions based on that in the ng-class

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/5487f896/5/

```
<tr ng-class="{pass: pass1, fail: !pass1 && finished}">
```

Comment: Awesome! Any chance you can tell me how you figured this out?

Comment: Mmm.. I thinks it's more experience than anything else, I've done a heavy angular project this year! Sorry this not a helpful answer :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that helps a lot.  Thanks for letting me have it the easy way.